Join and Meet in Finite Coxeter Groups
I am trying to prove Lemma 3.2.4 in the GTM book Combinatorics of Coxeter Groups. Any help is much appreciated.
Let me quote the Lemma:

Let $(W,S)$ be a Coxeter group, $w\in W$, $J\subseteq S$ with $W_J$ finite. 
(i) If $w\lhd_R ws$ $ \forall s\in J$, then $\bigvee\{ws\mid s\in J\}=ww_0(J)$. 
(ii) If $w\rhd_R ws$ $\forall s\in J$, then $\bigwedge\{ws\mid s\in J\}=ww_0(J)$.

$w_0(J)$ denotes the top element in the finite Coxeter group $W_J$. $\leq_R$ denotes the right weak order, and $\lhd_R$ denotes the right Bruhat cover. 
In the previous lemma, we know that when $W_J$ is finite, we have $\bigvee J=w_0(J)$ exists.
My attempt:  
Since $\bigvee J=w_0(J)$, we have $\forall s\in J$, $s\leq_Rw_0(J)$. By assumption, $w\lhd_R ws$ $\forall s\in J$. So we have $ws\leq_R ww_0(J)$ $\forall s\in J$. 
It remains to prove that $ww_0(J)$ is the "least" upper bound for $\{ws\mid s\in J\}$, and this is my first problem. 
If $u$ is another upper bound, then $ws\leq_R u$ $\forall s\in J$. 
The hint from the book is to use a previous result:

If $u\leq w$, then $[u,w]_R\cong [e,u^{-1}w]_R$.

I try to expand the reduced decompositions: 
Let $w=s_1\cdots s_q$, where $w_i\in S\setminus J$. Then $ws\leq_R u$ means $u=s_1\cdots s_qss'_1\cdots s'_p$ for some $s'_i\in S$. 
And then I have no idea how to proceed. It would be great if someone could guide me on (ii) as well.
Many thanks!
